# Convert char** to char[x][x]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, multidimensional-array

In C++, I want my class to have a char** field that will be sized with user input. Basically, I want to do something like this -

```
char** map;
map = new char[10][10];
```

with the 10's being any integer number. I get an error saying cannot convert char*[10] to char**. Why can it not do this when I could do -

```
char* astring;
astring = new char[10];
```

?

Comment: While this might be a very good homework (and you need to know it) you should probably use an stl type for this problem. So, as soon as you know how this works. Scrap the code and learn std::vector/string :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because **an array is not a pointer**.  Arrays *decay* into pointers to their first elements, but that happens only at the first level: a 2D array decays into a pointer to a 1D array, but that's it—it does not decay into a pointer to a pointer.

`operator new[]` allows to allocate a dynamic array of a size only known at runtime, but it only lets you allocate 1D arrays.  If you want to allocate a dynamic 2D array, you need to do it in two steps: first allocate an array of pointers, then for each pointer, allocate another 1D array.  For example:

```
char **map = new char*[10];  // allocate dynamic array of 10 char*'s
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    map[i] = new char[10];  // allocate dynamic array of 10 char's
```

Then to free the array, you have to deallocate everything in reverse:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    delete [] map[i];
delete [] map;
```

Comment: `a 2D array decays into a pointer to a 1D array` --> Do you mean: "a 2D array decays into a pointer to its first element"?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, like all arrays, a 2D array decays into a pointer to its first element, which in this case happens to be a 1D array.  A `char[10][10]` decays into a `char(*)[10]`, which is a "pointer to an array of 10 characters".  But that does not decay into a `char**`, since it is not an array type -- it is a pointer type.

Comment: @Adam: Oops, my bad; I thought it decays into a `char**` because they're all contiguous. Do you happen to know why it doesn't, though? Aren't they all contiguous?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, they are all contiguous.  If you have an array of 10 things, those 10 things are stored contiguously in memory.  If you take a pointer to one of those things, you can walk up and down the array by incrementing/decrementing your pointer by `sizeof(Thing)`.  In the case of `char x[10]`, `Thing` is `char` and `sizeof(Thing)` is 1; in the case of `char x[10][10]`, `Thing` is `char[10]` and `sizeof(Thing)` is 10.

Comment: (continued) The syntax `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`.  When you say `x[i][j]` (for `x` defined as `char x[10][10]`), the compiler translates that into "take the pointer to the first element of `x` (of type `char(*)[10]`), add in `i*sizeof(char[10]) = i*10` bytes to compute `x[i]`.  Then, dereference that (to obtain a `char[10]`) and add `j*sizeof(char) = j` bytes and dereference that to get `x[i][j]`."

Comment: @Adam: Oops sorry I had a typo in my comment... I definitely know it's not an array of pointers (that would have completely different semantics, I'm not having problems with that issue); that was a very ridiculous comment. :( I meant I thought it decays into a `char*` instead of a `char (*)[10]` -- any idea why it wouldn't?

Comment: (continued) Conversely, if `x` is a pointer to a pointer defined as `char **x`, the translation of `x[i][j]` is different: it means "take the pointer `x` and add `i*sizeof(char*) = i*4` bytes and dereference that to compute `x[i]`.  Then, add in `j*sizeof(char) = j` bytes and dereference that to get `x[i][j]`.  **An array is not a pointer**, I cannot stress that enough.  You can see the difference in the first array index computation: the number of bytes we need to offset by depends on the pointed-to type, which is different for arrays and pointers.

Comment: @Adam: Yeah sorry, I had a typo; I didn't mean `char**`, I was asking about `char*`. See my last comment.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The array `char x[10][10]` has the type "array 10 of array 10 of `char`".  The first element of `x` has type "array 10 of `char`".  The C language standard says that an array decays into a pointer to its first element; if the array has type "array of *type*", then the resulting pointer has type "pointer to *type*" (C99 §6.3.2.1/3), and pointers and arrays are fundamentally different types.  So in this case, the resulting pointer has type "pointer to array 10 of `char`", which is notated as `char (*)[10]`, and it's fundamentally a different type than "pointer to `char`".

Comment: @Adam: Huh, okay... yeah I guess it's a different type; I assumed that it might as well just be `char*` but I guess that wouldn't be too intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

On other hand, what the

```
map = new char[x][y];
```

really do is that, you new a array contain x items whose type is an array containing y items. And y must be a const integer.

So, if you really want your code pass without any problem, the correct way is

```
char (* map)[10] ;
map = new char[some_value_you_want][10];
```

Or more clearly,

```
typedef char array10[10];
array10 * map = new array10[some_value_you_want];
```

Answer (score -1):

Multi-dimentional arrays are not supported in that manner.  You need to allocate the two dimentions seperately.

```
char** map = new (char*)[10];

for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
  map[i] = new char[10];
}
```